# jQuery changing src of an iframe, stays changed after refresh

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have a weird issue.

I have one page which contains the menu and an iframe. When I click on one of the buttons from the menu, jQuery code changes the **src** attribute of the iframe. When the page loads, the iframe should display "**Home**". When I click one of the buttons, it should say "**Content**". This part works.

When I refresh the page, instead of "**Home**", the iframe show "**Content**" instead. It doesn't matter how much I refresh the page, it stays the same.

When I **close** the page and **reopen** it, the iframe displays "**Home**" again. When I click a button, the iframe shows again "**Content**" until I close and reopen it again.

Full code:
HTML

http://pastebin.com/Xe20yK8x

Full code jQuery:

http://pastebin.com/ZKTqG747
How can I make the iframe reset to its original source when I refresh the page ?

---

Edit:
After trying the suggestion made by Akash Rajbanshi, I got two results:

1) In Firefox, "**Home**" isn't shown, and "**Content**"still stays.

2) In Chrome, "**Home**" isn't shown too, but "**Content**" doesn't stay in the iframe after a refresh.

---

My Firefox version: 38.0.1

My Chrome version: 42.0

OS: Windows 8.1 (64-bit)

Comment: The problem you describe doesn't make sense on it's own, so you should paste more code. There could be a bug in your JavaScript causing this line to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `iframe src` to `home.html` on `document.ready()`.

### Example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contentIF').attr('src','Home.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these codes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#contentIF").attr("src", "home.html");
});
```

Edit:

Try adding this:

```
$("#contentIF").attr("src", "home.html");
```

above this:

```
document.getElementById('contentIF').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

OR 
you can use this:

```
document.getElementById('contentIF').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

(exclude `attr` function from jquery)

Read this [article](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp). 
As it Quotes:
*By default, the reload() method reloads the page from the cache, but you can force it to reload the page from the server by setting the forceGet parameter to true: location.reload(true)*

Interesting thing :D

Comment: @user220258 You can check out the updated answer. might be what you are looking for.

Comment: So I added the code you suggested:
It didn't work, but I tried running the code through Chrome (I use Firefox). When I refresh the page, nothing is showed on the iframe. Which m.akes things even weirder

Comment: have you tried the second code? you dont need to add the attr function, just add the true inside the reload function

Comment: Tried both, no effect in **Firefox**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78030/discussion-between-user220258-and-akash-rajbanshi).

Comment: I think you have working code...The next problem that might be is there are two jquery library present in the html file which might be causing this behaviour @user220258